# How can I use a HP G2 USB-C Dockingstation on Ubuntu to use my monitors?

Tags: usb, multiple-monitors, hardware, external-monitor, usb-c

I've been trying to connect my laptop via USB-C to my HP-G2 USB-C docking station for a few days now. The USB devices and also the LAN connection work, but my monitors are not addressed.
Does anyone know how to use a USB-C docking station to connect multiple monitors? Or what i have to adjust? I have only recently installed Ubuntu and haven't really changed anything relevant.... so it should still be the default settings.

I am still quite a Linux beginner and don't know how to solve this problem or if it is even possible. The docking station works  with multiple monitors on said laptop on Windows

Comment: Is the model of your notebook listed [in the compatibility list from HP](https://www.hp.com/us-en/shop/pdp/hp-usb-c-a-universal-dock-g2#techSpecs)? 

Comment: Not all USB-C ports support video. Unless explicitly mentioned in the official specification ALWAYS assume it hasn't. This is likely the problem here, not knowing your hardware, which has nothing to do with Linux or any other OS.

Comment: As is said, it works on this specific Laptop/Dockingstation-Setup (on Windows 10) to use my monitors